# Information about xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

I have enabled Xp_cmdshell extended stored procedure successfully.

I have typed the command

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'del C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\testdelete\CallRecordings\2020\05\05\Call'
```

and despite the file path is correct it indicates

[image]

Can anyone help why that doesn't work ?

Comment: First: why would you enable `xp_cmdshell`? Don't do that. Anything you think you want to use `xp_cmdshell` for should probably be getting handled by an external process that connects to SQL Server.

Comment: Second: What would `del C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\testdelete\CallRecordings\2020\05\05\Call` do at a Command Prompt? Try to delete `C:\Program`? Try instead `del "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\testdelete\CallRecordings\2020\05\05\Call"` with quotes (`"`).

Comment: i used " " and now it just indicates the path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\testdelete\CallRecordings\2020\05\05\Call\*, Are you sure (Y/N)?

Comment: HOW can i select Y to delete the file ?

Comment: This is yet another reason not to use `xp_cmdshell`: commands that prompt for input will block `xp_cmdshell` and never terminate. How would you do this from a Command Prompt? `del /f /q "C:\Path To Your\File"`

Comment: So you say xp_cmdshell cannot work. The fact is that afterwards i want to connect it to an sql job and delete files according to date. So i need to start from somewhere and i found xp_cmdshell command.

Comment: i have also used the command EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_delete_file 0, 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\testdelete\CallRecordings\2020\05\05\Call','.wav' but it just returns int value 0 and the file remains intact

Comment: i found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69885214/information-about-master-dbo-xp-delete-file/69894515#69894515

Comment: Why would you do this from TSQL anyway? TSQL is not a generalized scripting language, use Powershell, Python or similar

Comment: my superior told to find a way to do it like that.